# Configure SSL certificates with Hibernate, Spring and JDBC

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, ssl, pki

I'm trying to move from an unencrypted JDBC connection using a username and password to log in to my MySQL database server, to a connection using SSL and certificate-based authentication. I'm using Hibernate with Spring MVC. My WebAppConfig file looks like this:

```
package com.****.PolicyManager.init;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.sprhib")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig {


    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.urlSSL";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(
                PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, 
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, 
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = 
                new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

And my properties config file (application.properties) as follows:

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PolicyManager
db.urlSSL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PolicyManager?autoReconnect=true&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true
db.username=myuser
db.password=mypass

#Hibernate Configuration:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=com.****.PolicyManager.model
```

I've generated the right certificates inside /etc/mysql/certs and have edited my.cnf to point to then, but can't find any info online about how to configure my specific method of database initialisation to use certificate-based authentication to remove the need to store my database username and password in plain text on the server.

Can anyone suggest a solution or point me to a tutorial that uses this WebAppConfig.java file (hib properties, DriverManagerDataSource and LocalSessionFactoryBean) for it's configuration?

Comment: You shouldn't use `DriverManagerDataSource` for production, it isn't a connection pool and it is slow. You should use a proper connection pool.

Comment: What alternative data source should I be using?

Comment: A proper connection pool like [Commons-DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) or [Tomcat-JDBC](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html). There are plenty out there. The `DriverManagerDataSource` is nice for testing but not for production, for that you want a real connection pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL guide has [information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) on what to do on the client side, [this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68957) also has some detailed information.

It basically comes done to the following steps

1. Create a keystore and truststore with your clients certificate
2. Configure your environment (or a MysqlDataSource) to use these keystore and truststore
3. Configure the connection URL properly (which is what you apparently already have done).

And that should be it. The key is to have the correct certificates on the client side.

More information:

1. [Secure JDBC connection to MySQL from GlassFish](http://mjremijan.blogspot.nl/2011/04/secure-jdbc-connection-to-mysql-from.html)
2. [Secure JDBC connection to MySQL from Java](http://mjremijan.blogspot.nl/2011/04/secure-jdbc-connection-to-mysql.html)
3. [MySQL SSL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html)